# OOP design issue: inheritance vs. interface discovery

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Sorry for the lack of a better title; I couldn't think of a better one.

I have a class hierarchy like the following:

```
class Simulator
{
public:
    virtual void simulate(unsigned int num_steps);
};

class SpecializedSimulator1 : public Simulator
{
    Heap state1; Tree state2; // whatever
public:
    double speed() const;
    void simulate(unsigned int num_steps) override;
};

class SpecializedSimulator2 : public Simulator
{
    Stack state1; Graph state2;  // whatever
public:
    double step_size() const;
    void simulate(unsigned int num_steps) override;
};

class SpecializedSubSimulator2 : public SpecializedSimulator2
{
    // more state...
public:
    // more parameters...
    void simulate(unsigned int num_steps) override;
};

class Component
{
public:
    virtual void receive(int port, string data);
    virtual void react(Simulator &sim);
};
```

So far, so good.
Now it gets more complicated.

Components can support one *or more* types of simulation. (For example, a component that negates its input may support Boolean circuits as well as continuous-time simulation.) Every component "knows" what kinds of simulations it supports, and given a particular kind of simulator, it queries the simulator (via `dynamic_cast` or double dispatch or whatever means are appropriate) to find out how it needs to react.

Here's where it gets tricky:

Some `Component`s (say, imagine a `SimulatorComponent` class) themselves need to run sub-simulations inside of them. Part of this involves *inheriting* some properties of outer simulations, but potentially changing a few of them. For example, a continuous-time sub-simulator might want to lower its step size for its internal components in order to get better accuracy, but otherwise keep everything else the same.

Ideally, `SimulatorComponent` would be able to inherit from a class (say, `SpecializedSimulator2`) and override some subset of its properties as desired. The trouble, though, is that it has no idea whether the outer simulator's *most-derived* type is a `SpecializedSimulator2` -- it may very well be the case that `SimulatorComponent` is running inside a *more* specialized simulator than that, like a `SpecializedSubSimulator2`! In that case, sub-components of `SimulatorComponent` would need to be able to somehow get access to the properties of `SpecializedSubSimulator2` that they might need to access, but `SimulatorComponent` itself would not (and should not) be aware of these properties.

So, we see we can't use inheritance here.

Since the only means in C++ for "discovering" sub-interfaces like this is `dynamic_cast`, that means the sub-components must be able to *directly* access the outer simulator themselves, in order to run `dynamic_cast` on them. But if they do this, then `SimulatorComponent` can't intercept any of the calls.

At this point, I'm not sure what to do. The problem isn't *impossible* to solve, obviously -- I can think of some solutions (e.g. hierarchical key/value dictionary maintained at run-time) -- but the solutions involves some massive tradeoffs (e.g. less compile-time checking, performance loss, etc.) and make me wonder what I *should* be doing.

So, basically: how should I approach this problem? Is there a flaw in my design? Should I be solving this problem differently? Is there a design pattern for this that I'm just not aware of? Any tips?

Comment: Seriously you are losing me with all the simulation stuff. Can you perhaps take another example like game objects or something. Sounds like you want to cast something upwards but at the same time you don't want to do it.

Comment: @nilo: If I try to simplify it then people won't understand what the motivation is, so I'll end up getting answers that don't solve the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give a partial advice. For the situation in which you need to use a simulator inheriting properties from some parent then a cloning function could be the solution. This way you can ignore what actually the original simulation was, but anyway you end up with a new one with the same props.

It may just require some basic properties (like the simulation time step) which means you need to dynamic_cast to some intermediate class in your simulator hierarcy, but not exactly spot the right one.

Comment: I should have probably mentioned this, but there's no guarantee that the properties don't change... (think of a variable-step-size algorithm)